# Change elements of a vector

Tags: r, vector

Say I have a vector which has thousands of elements. What is the R code necessary if I want to make the elements at indices between 100-200 become 0?

Additionally how would I count the length between two different values, for example if I want  to know the length of time when the 'share price' is between 30-40?

Comment: I changed your tag from 'codes' (which isn't useful) to 'r', which is given your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please read the 'Introduction to R' manual that came with your installation.

One of your questions is simply

```
  X[ 100:200 ] <- 0
```

and the other operations are similar.  This is essential material, so you need to read up a little.