# How to replace vector occurring numbers?

Tags: r

Let's say I have a vector of 10 elements called `numbers` in R

```
numbers <- c(0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0)
```

and I want to replace each occurrence of 1 to 5?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In R , change the element of a vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631057/in-r-change-the-element-of-a-vector)

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
v[v==1]<-5
```